# html dropdownlist load first value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

**Controller**

```
 ViewBag.Districts = new SelectList(repoBPASFM.Map<DistrictDTOList>("GetDistrict"), "DistrictID", "DistrictName", null);
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label>
            District
        </label>
        <span class="text color-red">
            *
        </span>
        @Html.DropDownList("DistrictName", ViewData["Districts"] as SelectList,  new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
    </div>
```

I have this code above working fine it shows all the data in the dropdown. But I am having a problem, I want to auto-select the first item in the dropdown list upon loading the page.
My original code is `@Html.DropDownList("DistrictName", ViewData["Districts"] as SelectList,"",` it has a blank white space in the selection and I thought if I remove it it will auto-select the first item of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. You should remove the last param `null`, Because it's selected value.

```
ViewBag.Districts = new SelectList(repoBPASFM.Map<DistrictDTOList>("GetDistrict"), "DistrictID", "DistrictName");
```

2. You should replace the last param `null` by the value that you want to default

```
int selectedValue = 1;
ViewBag.Districts = new SelectList(repoBPASFM.Map<DistrictDTOList>("GetDistrict"), "DistrictID", "DistrictName", selectedValue);
```

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VMjrsC)

Comment: Sorry but still not displaying the first value.

Comment: The first answer is correct. I didn't notice that after it hit in controller it will check in my DB if there is a data. I just remove the null and its okay now.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying null instead of that could specify the DistrictID

```
 ViewBag.Districts = new SelectList(repoBPASFM.Map<DistrictDTOList>("GetDistrict"), "DistrictID", "DistrictName", 1);
```